# Meaning of "identify" in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me figure out the meaning of the words "identify" in the following context:

> The Seventh Plan made a significant effort to **identify** and promote
>   ‘beneficiary-oriented programme’ with the intention of extending
>   direct benefits to women.

You will find more context [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Pcf1nrvUwD0C&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=%22The%20Seventh%20Plan%20made%20a%20significant%20effort%20to%22&source=bl&ots=IPeL3jsgqU&sig=MUytBszAcKrmNslTUs5qrqT1xeI&hl=hi&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRj4j7-8TWAhXLrI8KHdDtC8gQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Seventh%20Plan%20made%20a%20significant%20effort%20to%22&f=false).

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: Yes. However, I am not sure if the author is referring to the current programmes.

Comment: When I clicked your link, I went to a webpage that says, "You have reached a page that is unavailable for viewing." You may want to replace your link with a screen shot. Also, when you are asked "Have you checked a dictionary?" that's really a hint that you should mention what you found in the dictionary in your question (not in a subsequent comment). [This meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) explains why.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence seems to incorporate some business jargon, and is not particularly clear.  For instance, I believe "programme" is singular, so we would expect either "promote a programme" or "promote programmes", but the above example seems incorrect.  That is also an unusual spelling, I typically see "program" or "programs", so I wonder if this has a special meaning in context.  (Perhaps this is just the British spelling, which I think should follow the rules for pluralization.)

We can simplify the example a little if we replace some of the more complex phrasing:

> [They] made a significant effort to identify and promote [programs] with the intention of [benefiting women].

In this case, we can see that the author is trying to combine two actions: identifying programs that benefit women, and promoting those programs.  It would be more clear to break those two ideas up:

> They made a significant effort to identify [programs] with the intention of [benefiting women], and then they made a significant effort to promote [those programs].

However, this phrasing is common for a speaker who is trying to convey an idea quickly to an audience that is already familiar with the topic.  For instance, a company might "sell and install solar panels", even though those are two very different activities.

Now that we have simplified the ideas, "identify" should be clear and the standard definition applies.  "They" are looking at many programs and deciding which programs fit the requirements.  Those programs are "identified" as being worth attention and promotion.